# Running PowerShell script locally from remote location

Tags: powershell

I am having an issue that I can't resolve.  I am trying to run a script locally on a server, the script exists on a remote server.  It is a script that I created that makes a series of domain credentials from a file with secure strings and a key file.

The script works fine locally if the ps1 file itself is on the system where I am running it.  I am unable to run the script locally if the ps1 file is on the other machine.

Here is the script that I am trying to run...  (this ps1 file is on "server1")

```
$creds = Import-Csv "\\server1\D$\Credentials\creds.csv"
$key = Get-Content "\\server1\D$\Resources\AES.key"
foreach ($cred in $creds) {
    $user = $cred.User
    $password = $cred.Hash | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key
    #$password = "" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $i = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user,$password
New-Variable -Name ($cred.Domain + "_Cred") -Value $i -Force -Verbose
}
```

I am trying to run it from server2 using the following command...

```
& '\\server1\D$\Credentials\BuildCreds.ps1'
```

Any thoughts?  Is this a scope issue, or the fact that I am loading the files with UNC?  I've tried everything that I can think of.

Comment: Error messages would be useful.

Comment: Never seen a `:` in a unc path before (`\\server1:\Credentials`), that looks like an error. Always been `\\server\share\folder\file.txt`

Comment: You're also likely to be having a [Kerberos Double Hop problem](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2016/08/30/powershell-remoting-kerberos-double-hop-solved-securely/) "I am on ServerA, connected to ServerB where I need to reach ServerC. I have permissions to ServerC, but I still get Access Denied. Default Kerberos rules prevent ServerB from passing credentials to ServerC."

Comment: There is no server C though.  No error messages.  I run everything as verbose and it looks like it works, but no credentials are created.

Comment: The \\server1:\Credentials is correct.  I changed it because I am running it from the D$ share.

Comment: You're connecting to a remote computer, that is then connecting to another computer that isn't itself. That's a double hop. The D$ share on your server would be `\\server1\D$\Credentials` not `\\server1:\Credentials`.

Comment: I am not connecting to a third computer.  I am in a PS session on server 2.  I am running the script that is on the D$ share on server 1.  The supporting files are on server 1.

Comment: I have corrected the question to clear up the share issue.  The script does run, and appears to run correctly, without error.  I see the verbose output on Server2.  No credentials are created though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this issue only exists in PowerShell ISE.  I ran the code in PowerShell and everything worked correctly.

I am not quite sure why it is like that.